# Динамические запросы

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Можно ли в Hibernate сущности замапить не на конкретную таблицу, а на предопределенные запросы?

Т.е. пусть у меня есть класс

```
class Test {
  private int Id;
  private String Name;
  private String Remark;
}
```

и в базе есть таблица такой структуры

```
CREATE TABLE sqls (
  `name` VARCHAR,
  `select` CLOB,
  `refresh` CLOB,
  `insert` CLOB
  `update` CLOB
  `delete` CLOB
);
INSERT INTO sqls (
  `name`, `select`, `refresh`, `insert`, `update`, `delete`
) VALUES (
  "TEST",
  "SELECT id, name, remark FROM mytable",
  "SELECT id, name, remark FROM mytable WHERE id = :id",
  "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, remark) VALUES (:id, :name, :remark)",
  "UPDATE mytable SET name = :name, remark = :remark WHERE id = :id",
  "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = :id"
);
```

и я хочу, чтобы мой класс работал не напрямую с таблицей `mytable`, а через такие предопределенные запросы. Само собой запросы будут не такие простые. Будут и джойны и вызов процедур для вставки/обновления

Если Hibernate такого не умеет, то есть ли ORMы с таким функционалом?

Comment: Механизм @ NamedQueries и @ NamedQuery как раз позволяет выполнять предопределённые запросы. Ими нужно аннотировать Entity. Также существуют @ NamedNativeQueries @ NamedNativeQuery

Comment: @manymny Из того, что я нашел. 1) Запрос можно определить только при компиляции. В рантайме нельзя. (Или вручную собирать конфиг) 2) Можно определить только SELECT запрос. Какой-нибудь INSERT/UPDATE **для конкретной сущности** определить не получится вообще

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/67304-hibernate-named-query-for-insert-update-and-delete?p=460452#post460452.

Comment: @manymny Спасибо. Как раз мой случай. `ORM is not applicable when you have rules that don't map to the ORM logic.` И последним постом прямое выполнение UPDATE без привязки к сущности.